# How do you populate a ListBox with items read from a text file

Tags: c#, user-interface, file-io, listbox

So I tried reading the file and I confirmed it worked and then tried adding the contents to a listbox and it did not work. The way I do it is first read the file, split the file line by line and put the contents into a string array, then use a for loop to add the contents to a listbox. At first my problem was the listbox not having the contents added, then something changed and now it looks like the file isn't being read properly. I don't know if it affects anything but I did edit the file in Visual Studio so I wouldn't think that affect anything, but I'm mentioning it just in case. I am also using holdLine more than once since I am reading more than one file.

Here is where I am reading the file

```
using (StreamReader inOFile = new StreamReader("..\\..\\options.txt"))
{               
    while (!inOFile.EndOfStream)
    {
        holdLine = inOFile.ReadLine();
        OptionsArr = holdLine.Split('\n');  
    }
```

The file in question has these lines

- Employee ID
- Name
- Department
- Employment Status
- Salary

The code where I try to add the contents of the string array to the listbox

```
OptionsListBox.Items.Clear();

OptionsListBox.BeginUpdate();
           
//one way I tried            
string listOptions = string.Join(" ", Program.OptionsArr);
OptionsListBox.Items.Add(listOptions.ToString());
              
//different way i tried
for (int i = 0; i < Program.OptionsArr.Length; i++)
{                 
    OptionsListBox.Items.Add(Program.OptionsArr[i]);
}
                  

//another failed attempt
OptionsListBox.Items.AddRange(Program.OptionsArr);

OptionsListBox.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: I would suggest you parse the file into a `List<Employee>`, override `ToString` to display whatever you want the UI to show, and use the List as the `DataSource`.  Plenty of wonderful and useful things to learn along the way

Comment: Is there really not a way to just make the array contents be put into the listbox? That's only one problem that I have. There's still the file not being read problem. I don't know why it's happening. I write the contents out to the console and when I run with debugging the contents don't show up.

Comment: You're using ReadLine() and then trying to do a Split('\n') on the result. The results of ReadLine() are **already** split by '\n', so your split will have no effect.

Comment: You'll need to include some of the file you're trying to read. It's not clear from your example how the file is formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem. I added some Console.WriteLine() to print out what is in the variables during and after the loop. (here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5VibfK))

```
using System;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    const string _textFile = "This is the first line in the file\n"
                           + "This is the second line in the file\n"
                           + "This is the third line in the file\n";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_textFile);
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(utf8);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        
        string wholeLine;
        string[] optionsArray;

        using (var inOFile = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
        {           
            var count = 0;
            while (!inOFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                wholeLine = inOFile.ReadLine();
                optionsArray = wholeLine.Split('\n');
                
                Console.WriteLine("Reading Line {0}", ++count);
                Console.WriteLine("\tWhole: '{0}'", wholeLine);
                Console.WriteLine("\tSplit: '{0}'", string.Join("', '", optionsArray));
                Console.WriteLine()
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Final Options Array: {0}", string.Join(" | ", optionsArray));
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
Reading Line 1
    Whole: 'This is the first line in the file'
    Split: 'This is the first line in the file'

Reading Line 2
    Whole: 'This is the second line in the file'
    Split: 'This is the second line in the file'

Reading Line 3
    Whole: 'This is the third line in the file'
    Split: 'This is the third line in the file'

Final Options Array: This is the third line in the file
```

Notice how optionsArray only contains one item in it? And it's exact copy of wholeLine? That's because the ReadLine() function removes all the line breaks in the data. .Split('\n') won't be able to split anything.

If I change the split character to a space, then I get this:

```
Reading Line 1
    Whole: 'This is the first line in the file'
    Split: 'This', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'line', 'in', 'the', 'file'

Reading Line 2
    Whole: 'This is the second line in the file'
    Split: 'This', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'line', 'in', 'the', 'file'

Reading Line 3
    Whole: 'This is the third line in the file'
    Split: 'This', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'line', 'in', 'the', 'file'

Final Options Array: This | is | the | third | line | in | the | file
```

In this case, each line is split into separate words because they are separated by a space ' '. But even if I change the splitting, optionsArray only contains the **last** line in the file. Your while loop is written to read the entire file, but since you never **do** anything to collect the results of the split operating, the rest of your code won't do anything.

Comment: The formatting for my file isn't  anything special. Its the lines I have earlier in my post one after another no formatting. Anyways thank you for your answer. I figured out what I needed to do. I decided to just use ReadAllLines method to assign the contents of the file to the OptionsArr array

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
// Employee is a class with employee fields (EmployeeID, name...)
IList<Employee> employees = readEmployeesFromFile();
OptionsListBox.DataSource = employees;
OptionsListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
OptionsListBox.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
```